# While loop to for loop

Tags: for-loop, while-loop

I am struggling with loops can someone help me change this while loop into a for loop. The task is for the program to iterate over a string of numbers and see if there is a number in the next position.

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

while (data.hasNextInt()) {

    j = data.nextInt();
    numbers.add(i,j);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: You need to give us more context, in the form of a [mcve] and a proper language tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what language this is, but it  should look something like:

```
for(int i = 0, j = 0; data.hasNextInt(); i++)
{
    j = data.nextInt();
    numbers.add(i,j);
}
```

Depending on whether you need the value of i and j after the loop is done and your languages variable scoping rules you may want to keep them declared outside of the loop.